# Can't save value by gin-contrib/sessions (maybe value is too large)

Tags: api, go, session, cookies, jwt

I cannot save RefreshToken on session.

In the code below, refreshToken is constant, but Actually it is created by AWS Cognito.

Is there any workaround??

thank you

```
import(
    "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions"
    "github.com/gin-contrib/sessions/cookie"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
  router := gin.Default()
  store := cookie.NewStore([]byte("secret"))
  router.Use(sessions.Sessions("mysession", store))

  router.GET("ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
    session := sessions.Default(c)
    
    accessToken = "dfasdfasdf..."() //length is 1086
    session.Set("at", accessToken)
    refreshToken = "dfasdfasdf..."() //length is 1802
    session.Set("at", refreshToken)
    
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "pong")
  })

  router.GET("ping2", func(c *gin.Context) {
    session := sessions.Default(c)
    
    session := sessions.Default(c)
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{
        "at": session.Get("at"),
        "rt": session.Get("rt"),
    })
    
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "pong")
  })
  router.Run(":8080")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call `session.Save()` after using `session.Set`.

e.g.

```
session.Set("accessToken", accessToken)
session.Set("refreshToken", refreshToken)
session.Save()
```